# fetchApi Firefox extention on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a simple firefox extension, which connects to a local http server and asks for permissions for site. (The server is a simpleHttp Server with a Cors Header.)

--extension code--

```
allowed();

function allowed() {
  r = window.location.href;
  console.log("hi")
    fetch('http://localhost:8081/site_x?s='+r,{
    mode: "cors",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "text/plain"
    }})
    .then((response) =>response.text())
  .then((data) => {
      if(data=="True"){
        window.location.href = "https://www.yofla.com/black-screen/#";
      }
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
  });
  }
```

-- i get a network error in firefox console.

-- Mainifest file

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Productivity",
  "version": "0.0.1b",

  "description": "Some describtion",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/Logo48.png",
    "96": "icons/Logo96.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ipinfo.io/*",
    "http://localhost:8081/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "jQuery-min-3.4.1.js","connect.js" ]
    }
  ]

}
```

i think it was to do with the permissions, because this code works on https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?_______

Comment: You've tagged this with `google-chrome-extension` so beware this approach won't work in Chrome because it disallows cross-origin requests in content scripts (extensions should do it in their background script or popup script).

Answer (score 2):

I moved the fetch to background script and ran the server on port 80 , but still...

background-script.js

```
async function handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    let r = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1/site_x?s='+request.greeting,{
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/plain"
        }
    });
    let data = await r.text();
    sendResponse({response: data});
}

function normal(request, sender, sendResponse){
    handleMessage(request, sender, sendResponse);
}
    
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(normal);
```

content-script.js

```
function handleResponse(message) {
    console.log(`Message from the background script:  ${message.response}`);
}

function handleError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

function notifyBackgroundPage(e) {
    var sending = browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    greeting: e
    });
    sending.then(handleResponse, handleError);  
}

notifyBackgroundPage("test");
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Productivity",
    "version": "0.0.1b",

    "description": "Adds a red border to all webpages matching mozilla.org.",

    "icons": {
    "48": "icons/Logo48.png",
    "96": "icons/Logo96.png"
    },
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
        "js": [ "jQuery-min-3.4.1.js","connect.js" ]
    }
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ipinfo.io/*",
    "http://localhost/*",
    "http://127.0.0.1/*",
    "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

Comment: `http://localhost/*` at permissions section within `manifest.json` helps me a lot. Thanks.